# Tangling non-code files to separate files

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a number of parameter files that my code needs as inputs and I would like them all to be in the same org file in different blocks and have them all tangled to different files.

Can I somehow tangle `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE ... #+END_EXAMPLE` blocks or some other block type? I tried this which didn't work:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE :tangle methanol.rtf

MASS     1 H      1.00800 H ! polar H
...
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Alternatively can I define new languages for org-mode to recognize but not execute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `fundamental` as "language", i.e. replace your example by:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC fundamental :tangle methanol.rtf

MASS     1 H      1.00800 H ! polar H
...
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I have something in the block that take the form of an org-mode header, I've posted another question http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/tangling-fundamental-source-blocks-with-org-header-like-code

Comment: org 0.9 this throws an error: `org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for fundamental!` any idea?

Comment: @doctorate That source code block is not intended to be executed. Don't press `C-c C-c` on it! The original poster only wants to tangle.

Comment: I see, so `C-c C-v t`.