# Tangling fundamental source blocks with org-header like code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a code blocks for a domain specific input files that I want to have in a single org file and tangle them out to separate files (see [Tangling non-code files to separate files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19648/tangling-non-code-files-to-separate-files/19651#19651)). However, my source has things in it that look like org-mode headings, e.g.:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC fundamental :tangle test.inp
* minimize
*

open unit 10 read form name methanol.rtf
read rtf card unit 10
close unit 10
...
#+END_SRC
```

and these don't get tangled. Removing the `* minimize` line or putting any amount of text before it does not solve the problem. The "headers" aren't highlighted but they still have folding etc., and emacs won't let me put spaces in front of them.

Seems like a bug, but a workaround would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you did trick org-mode. You did not use <kbd>C-'</kbd> to input the text block.

If you do so, the org-mode syntax is escaped as the following example shows. Note the commas before the stars! They are automatically added by org-babel.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC fundamental :tangle test.inp
,* minimize
,*

open unit 10 read form name methanol.rtf
read rtf card unit 10
close unit 10
...

#+END_SRC
```

If you input a new source code block the sequence is:

1. Start on a new line and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to get the right indentation.
2. Input `<s` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> for the easy template that generates a source code block.
3. Input `fundamental :tangle test.inp` to complete the header of the source code block
4. Press <kbd>C-'</kbd> to edit the source code block.
5. In the newly opened buffer paste your text.
6. Finish editing the source code block with <kbd>C-'</kbd>

Comment: Lesson learned, haha!

Comment: @Tobias, thank you for this info. I was trying to grasp where did these commas in my code blocks came from, and this was the first good hint I found in this respect.